# Daemon Process Acting as TCP Proxy Server

Tags: c, sockets, server, proxy, daemon

I have a C program that I am trying to implement a daemon process that acts as a general TCP proxy server. I believe I have completed mostly everything correct but there is a while loop that I cannot figure out. Below is my code and I will put *** around what I am having trouble with.

Program descriptions

(1) The daemon listens for TCP connections on a specified port number.
(2) When a new client initiates a TCP connection request, the daemon accepts the request and
establishes a new TCP connection with the new client.
(a) The daemon forks a child process that is dedicated to handling the new client.
(b) The child process establishes a new TCP connection to a pre-assigned port on the actual
targeted server.
(c) The child process falls into a loop in which it acts as an intermediator exchanging data
(reading/writing or writing/reading) between the client and the targeted server.
(3) Once a child has been forked, the daemon process resumes listening for additional TCP
connections from other clients.

```
#ifndef unix 
#define closesocket close 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <netdb.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#endif

#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>


#define PROTOPORT       5100            /* default protocol port number */ 
#define QLEN            6               /* size of request queue        */

int visits = 0;
int     argc; 
char    *argv[];

int main()  // works as "server" side 
{        
    struct  hostent  *ptrh; /* pointer to a host table entry       */        
    struct  protoent *ptrp; /* pointer to a protocol table entry   */        
    struct  sockaddr_in sad; /* structure to hold server's address  */        
    struct  sockaddr_in cad; /* structure to hold client's address  */        
    int     sd0, sd1; /* socket descriptors                  */        
    int     port; /* protocol port number                */        
    int     addrlen; /* length of address                   */
    pid_t   pid;

    memset((char *)&sad, 0, sizeof(sad)); /* clear sockaddr structure */        
    sad.sin_family = AF_INET;  /* set family to Internet   */        
    sad.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;     /* set the local IP address(not specify, reserved */

    if(argc > 1){
        port = atoi(argv[1]);
    }

    else port = PROTOPORT; /* use the specified port number */        

    if (port > 0)                   /* test for illegal value       */                
        sad.sin_port = htons((u_short)port);        
    else 
    { /* print error message and exit */                
        fprintf(stderr,"bad port number %s\n", argv[1]);                
        exit(1);        
    }

    /* Map TCP transport protocol name to protocol number */ 
    if( ((int)(ptrp = getprotobyname("tcp"))) == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot map \"tcp\" to protocol number");
        exit(1);
    } 

    /* Create a socket */        
    sd0 = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, ptrp->p_proto);       
    if(sd0 < 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "socket creation failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Bind a local address to the socket */        
    // bind()
    if (bind(sd0, (struct sockaddr *)&sad, sizeof(sad)) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr,"bind failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Listen at the port */        
    // listen() 
    /* Specify size of request queue */
    if (listen(sd0, QLEN) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr,"listen failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }



    /* Main server loop - accept and handle requests */        
    while (1) 
    { 
        // accept request
        addrlen = sizeof(cad);
        sd1 = accept(sd0, (struct sockaddr *)&cad, &addrlen);
        // fork a process
        pid = fork();
        if(pid == 0)  // child process 
        { 
            //close oldsocket;
            close(sd0);
            HandleClientConnection(sd1); 
            break; 
        } 
        else /*parant process */
        { 
            close(sd1); 
            continue; 
        } 
    } 
    return 0; 
}

// implement "HandleClientConnection(new socket1)" - works as "client" side 
HandleClientConnection(newsocket1) 
{ 
    // general socket settings at the client side
    struct  hostent  *ptrh;  /* pointer to a host table entry       */        
    struct  protoent *ptrp;  /* pointer to a protocol table entry   */        
    struct  sockaddr_in sad; /* structure to hold an IP address     */        
    int     newsocket2;      /* socket descriptor                   */        
    int     port;            /* protocol port number                */        
    char    *host;           /* pointer to host name                */        
    int     n, n2;           /* number of characters read           */        
    char    buf[1000];       /* buffer for data from the server     */ 
    int i;

        memset((char *)&sad,0,sizeof(sad)); /* clear sockaddr structure */        
        sad.sin_family = AF_INET;         /* set family to Internet     */


    ***while(1) /* get the real server's IP addr from "GET" command  */ 
    {  
        // read to buffer and compare, such as 
        if(strncmp("GET", buf[i-1], 3) == 0 || strncmp("CONNECT", buf[i-1], 7) == 0) 
        { 
            while(1) 
            { 
                //...; // read more


                if(strncmp("Host", buf[i-1], 4) == 0) 
                {  
                    //...; 
                    printf("\nfound the host name.\n"); 
                    //...; 
                }
            } 
            break;
        }
    }***

        /* Convert real host name to equivalent IP address and copy to sad. */        
        // gethostbyname();
        ptrh = gethostbyname(host);        
        if ( ((char *)ptrh) == NULL ) 
        {                
            fprintf(stderr,"invalid host: %s\n", host);                
            exit(1);        
        }        
        memcpy(&sad.sin_addr, ptrh->h_addr, ptrh->h_length);

        /* Map TCP transport protocol name to protocol number. */
        if ( ((int)(ptrp = getprotobyname("tcp"))) == 0) {                
            fprintf(stderr, "cannot map \"tcp\" to protocol number");                
            exit(1);        
        }

        /* Create a newsocket2. */        
        // socket();
        newsocket2 = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, ptrp->p_proto);        
        if (newsocket2 < 0) {                
            fprintf(stderr, "socket creation failed\n");               
            exit(1);        
        }

        /* Connect the socket to the specified server. */        
        // connect()
        if (connect(newsocket2, (struct sockaddr *)&sad, sizeof(sad)) < 0) {                
            fprintf(stderr,"connect failed\n");                
            exit(1);        
        } 

        // Repeatedly read data from client (newsocket1) and write to server' side (newsocket2)
        n = recv(newsocket1, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);        
        while (n > 0) {               
             write(newsocket2,buf,n);                
             n = recv(newsocket1, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);        
        }

        // Repeatedly read data from server' side (newsocket2) and write to client (newsocket1).
        n2 = recv(newsocket2, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);        
        while (n2 > 0) {                
            write(newsocket1,buf,n2);                
            n2 = recv(newsocket2, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);        
        }

        // Close the newsocket2
        close(newsocket2);
}
```

Comment: What is the question. Also consider formatting the description using paragraphs, bullets, etc. It will be easier to read and provide feedback.

Comment: on a linux OS, the posted code does not even come close to compiling (much less cleanly compiling).   When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results.

Comment: Regarding: `#ifndef unix .... #endif`  the *nix OSs need the header files that are being 'skipped' via this conditional compile statement.  so why have them not `#include'd`?  If your working with windows, still need those header files as the posted code does not contain the function names used in windows

Comment: regarding: `if( ((int)(ptrp = getprotobyname("tcp"))) == 0) {`  This returns a pointer to a `struct protoent`, or, if no name found, then returns NULL, not an `int`  so why is it being cast to `int`?  This is the struct: ` struct protoent {
               char  *p_name;       /* official protocol name */
               char **p_aliases;    /* alias list */
               int    p_proto;      /* protocol number */
           }`

Comment: OT regarding: `fprintf(stderr, "cannot map \"tcp\" to protocol number");`  Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  And when the error is from a C library function, then should also output the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  The function: `perror()` handles all this very nicely.

Comment: regarding: `int     addrlen;`  This is being used as the third parameter to `accept()`  The function `accept()` is expecting a parameter of type: `socklen_t`  which is not an `int`.  Rather, it is an `unsigned int`   Suggest: `socklen_t addrlen = 0;`

Comment: regarding: `int     argc; 
char    *argv[];

int main()` and `if(argc > 1){
        port = atoi(argv[1]);
    }`  This will not work.  Suggest: `int main( int argc, char* argv[] )`  And when the value in `argc` is not the expected value, then should output a message similar to: `fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s portNum\n", argv[0] );`

Comment: in function: `main()`  regarding the statement: `HandleClientConnection(sd1);`  The compiler has not yet seen this function, so has no idea what it is expected to do.  To fix this, before the function: `main()` insert the prototype statement for that function.  I.E. ` void HandleClientConnection(socket_t newsocket1);`   Then write the signature for the function the same way (without the trailing `;`)

Comment: regarding: `if(strncmp("GET", buf[i-1], 3) == 0 || strncmp("CONNECT", buf[i-1], 7) == 0)`  the variable `i` is not initialized (nor updated).

Comment: There are LOTS of syntax errors and some logic errors in the posted code besides those listed in the above comments

Comment: regarding: `memset((char *)&sad,0,sizeof(sad)); /* clear sockaddr structure */        
        sad.sin_family = AF_INET;`  there are three fields to be set in a `struct sockaddr_in` not just 1

Comment: regarding: `int     port;`  a `port` is a `short int`, not an `int`

Comment: the functions: `recv()` and `write()` return type is `ssize_t`, not `int`  and every such call needs to have (at a minimum) the returned value checked.  Strongly suggest reading/understanding the MAN page for each C library function used.  This kind of search string: `man page for recv` will work for each of the functions used.

Comment: regarding; `if(pid == 0)  // child process 
        { 
            //close oldsocket;
            close(sd0);
            HandleClientConnection(sd1); 
            break; 
        } 
        else /*parant process */
        { 
            close(sd1); 
            continue; 
        }`   The function: `fork()` can also return a value <0 when an error occurs.  The code should be checking for the <0 rather than assuming that the call to `fork()` was successful.

Comment: regarding: `  n = recv(newsocket1, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);        
        while (n > 0) {               
             write(newsocket2,buf,n);                
             n = recv(newsocket1, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);        
        }

        // Repeatedly read data from server' side (newsocket2) and write to client (newsocket1).
        n2 = recv(newsocket2, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);        
        while (n2 > 0) {                
            write(newsocket1,buf,n2);                
            n2 = recv(newsocket2, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);`  (cont)

Comment: (cont)  This pair of loops has a couple of logic problems.  Suggest becoming familiar with the `select()` function